# Pergunta de concurso feita, o que fazer?

Tags: debate, perguntas

O que fazer com esse tipo de [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181591/quest%C3%A3o-de-concurso-c%C3%B3digo-em-java)?

Li que não é permitido pedir que usuários respondam completamente a perguntas de faculdade, essa pergunta é de múltipla escolha ou seja, pode gerar respostas como:

A certa é a letra (letra), não é o caso dessa pergunta, porém no título deixou intuitivo a que pediria qual é a alternativa correta.

O que fazer com ela?

Comment: Onde leu que não pode pedir resposta a perguntas de faculdade?

Comment: Me refiro a solução completa de uma pergunta de faculdade. Vou alterar.

Comment: Mas ali não pede uma solução completa.

Comment: Pedidos de tarefas (trabalho de faculdade) são praticamente negativados e fechados na hora.

Comment: Certo, não pede uma solução completa, mas como o Wallace disse, foi mal formulada já no título: colocando Questão de concurso: código em java

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108887/101

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum pedir uma resolução de tarefa, desde que encaixe nas regras do site. O problema das tarefas não é proibição, e sim o fato de normalmente estarem associadas à falta de qualidade, escopo e/ou objetividade.

Comment: a pergunta mencionada é perfeita válida

Answer (score 13):

A pergunta é sobre programação com o problema bem definido?

Está clara?

É objetiva?

Não existe no site?

Tem foco e permite uma resposta canônica?

Respondeu sim para tudo isto?

Então qual é o problema dela?

Se alguém responder a letra e mais nada será uma resposta ruim, é problema da resposta. É óbvio que a pessoa quer saber o porquê daquilo e não só a resposta. Como foi bem respondido. A pergunta até já dá a resposta correta, ele quer saber o motivo.

O motivo da pessoa perguntar, a origem da dúvida, nada disso importa, importa é o conteúdo postado.

Essa pergunta está boa, podia estar ligeiramente melhor, principalmente o título (que alguém pode ler o corpo e fazer um título melhor, a edição é permitida para todos justamente para isso), mas não vejo problemas sérios nela.

A pergunta é perfeitamente respondível, como de fato foi com maestria.

Comment: Acho que seria ideal uma especificação de o que o usuário tem dúvida nesse caso, além da edição no título, na minha opinião ao menos o usuário não foi claro perante no que ele tem dúvida.

Answer (score 8):

Eu respondi a questão e quero frisar o seguinte:

O autor da pergunta claramente deseja entender porque a resposta do gabarito é a letra D:

> O gabarito diz que a correta é a letra D, mas estou com dúvidas nessa questão.

Embora ele não tenha sido claro em quais são as dúvidas que ele tem, é óbvio que só poderia ser porque ele não entende/entendia o motivo pelo qual a alternativa D seria correta. Isso é algo que arrumei facilmente ao editar a pergunta.

Isso é mais ou menos o mesmo que perguntar isso:

> Esse código imprime 40 e lança uma `ClassCastException`, por quê? Ou será ele faz alguma outra coisa?

O que é uma pergunta perfeitamente válida.

Se alguém viesse e respondesse apenas "a alternativa correta é a D", essa seria uma resposta de péssima qualidade, afinal de contas isso já estava na própria pergunta!

Isso não é uma questão do tipo "faça meu trabalho de faculdade para mim", uma vez que a prova já foi feita, o gabarito publicado e a resposta do gabarito está na própria pergunta.

Neste momento, a pergunta está com +2/-7 votos. Um dos votos positivos é meu. A meu ver é uma pergunta perfeitamente válida e não acho que mereça os votos negativos que tem (mas aí, isso já é uma opinião minha, cada um vota do jeito que quiser no fim das contas).

Comment: O outro é meu..

Comment: Positivei agora depois das edições, assim como outros parecem estar fazendo.

Answer (score 3):

Questões sobre concursos ou certificações podem gerar boas respostas mas não basta dizer "a letra **C** é  correta" o próprio gabarito já faz isso, precisa de uma argumentação de qual é a alternativa certa ou porque a outra bem parecida é errada, geralmente vai um explicação do contexto e motivo daquela aplicação. Uma boa explicação pode servir de recurso no caso de alternativas divergentes.

O ponto negativo sobre esse tipo de questão é que mesmo bem formatada e com todos os detalhes possível pode ser facilmente fechada como baseada em opiniões ou não está clara.

Algumas bancas elaboram questões tão ruins que posteriormente são anuladas seja porque copiaram algo errado, frases retiradas de um livro sem o devido contexto, uso de termos traduzidos que tornam a interpretação ambígua.

Comment: Eu achei nesse caso em específico que o usuário não especificou a dúvida, ele apenas disse que está em dúvida, mas em que? Não negativei a questão, a resposta parece estar boa, mas seria melhor se a pergunta fosse mais objetiva. Pelo menos na minha opinião :/

Comment: Eu acho que o problema já começa no título: "Questão de concurso: código em java". Isso não descreve o problema. Pelo menos eu vi que a edição foi milgrau.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold poderia ter deixado um comentário como vc mesmo sugeriu `dúvida, mas em que?` ou `pq você acha que a letra B é a correta` ? já melhora bastante o entendimento. Já o título é certeza que precisa de um melhor aquele primeiro entenda como provisório :P

Comment: @rray acabei não deixando um comentário pois a pergunta tinha uma resposta boa rsrs, porém não fiz a pergunta no meta por mal, só quero esclarecer uma dúvida, pois ao ler o título já se tira conclusões precipitadas sobre a pergunta, mesmo ela sendo válida como é o caso.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold essa pergunta do meta é importante para esclarecer mesmo :). Ao ver um título `Questão 39 concurso ABC - UML` se você conhece ou entende assunto mude para algo adequado sem medo, algo como `Dúvida em ação assincrona no diagrama de interação` esse é um título mais ou menos ainda dá para refinar mais um pouco :)

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião, desde que a pergunta seja bem formatada, não é problema.

A questão é que tudo nesse caso pode depender tanto do bom-senso de quem  pergunta e também de quem responde.

Pense nisso: Se a pergunta que poderia abordar um assunto interessante, mas como ela pede para responder uma das opções, provavelmente um "respondedor" daqueles do tipo "de poucas palavras" vai apenas querer colocar o valor da resposta. Aí isso poderia ser ruim.

No final das contas, acho que não importa o motivo da pergunta, e sim a formatação. Ela tem que estar adequada ao formato do site, para que ela seja respondida.

Para ter qualidade, creio que depende da pergunta e da resposta.

Se pensar bem, o título "Questão de concurso: código em Java" já demonstra que a pergunta foi muito mal formulada (eu julgo o livro pela capa, porque a capa tem que mostrar o que livro tem em resumo).

Por outro lado a resposta parece estar muito boa.

Talvez fosse o caso da nossa equipe de editores avaliar uma forma de colocar a pergunta dentro do escopo.

O @Gabe já me sugeriu que em alguns casos é melhor que a gente edite a pergunta.

Eu confesso que negativei a pergunta pela má qualidade, mas eu acredito que devemos usar um tempo também para poder editar ao invés de dar apenas o "negativo da crítica". É claro que há alguns casos que é quase irrecuperável, mas como já tem uma resposta nessa pergunta, a minha sugestão é uma edição (com o concesso do AP, pra não dar confusão).

Answer (score 0):

A coisa mais fácil é disfarçar uma questão de prova e colocar aqui no site.

Muito dificilmente a pessoa vai ter a prova inteira respondida por aqui antes de entregar ao professor, em menos de uma hora.

Para usar o celular e colar por aqui, sem saber se a resposta é realmente a correta, eu acharia melhor colar de um livro, site ou do caderno.

Responda bla bla bla:

(a) email
(b) site
(c) chat

Qual o problema em responder a pessoa?

Como vamos distinguir:

- se a pessoa está no colégio, na faculdade ou em casa?
- se é ou não é questão de prova?
- se a pessoa não sabe ou apenas quer confirmar uma resposta?

O motivo do site existir é a ajuda mútua respondendo perguntas não importando o formato que estejam, quem fez ou para qual motivo foi feito, o importante é tirar a dúvida de uma pessoa.

Se fizermos uma enquete aqui eu acho que 99% das pessoas que participam daqui do site seriam alunos ou profissionais da área de informática.

Nesse caso não há nada que possa ser feito sem discriminar pessoas e respostas e sem ir contra o objetivo principal do site.

Por mim responderíamos a tudo e a todos.

Comment: Só discordo do "não importando o formato que estejam". O site funciona melhor que os outros pelo fato de ter regras claras, que foram projetadas com base em toda uma experiência do que funciona e o que não. É de se esperar que quem pergunte, observe o formato correto. Jogar de qualquer jeito uma dúvida confusa aqui, ou ficar discutindo coisas de maneira não objetiva, por exemplo, não deve ser aceito nunca, tampouco respondido no chute ou incentivado. É como você ir ao cinema, e achar ruim ter que pegar a fila e se achar no direito de passar na frente de todo mundo que está respeitando a ordem.

Comment: O fato de postar uma questão mal elaborada tira a proposta da nossa comunidade, que é perguntas claras, objetivas e com respostas de qualidade, se permitirmos qualquer formato de questão viraremos um yahoo respostas, eu questionei essa questão em específico porque antes de ser editada estava com sérios problemas no título principalmente.